# sub folder in not creating on azure in asp.net mvc5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I am ruing my website on azure, every folder is present on site directory in azure but uploadimages is my sub folder of content is absent from wwwroot, and images is not uploading also
I am using 
var path =Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages/")+filename);
same with document upload

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify if you're using Azure Web Apps (formerly web sites) or something else - you tagged it as Web Apps, but just want to be clear. Also, how did you confirm the subfolder or uploaded images aren't in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have tested on my side, please follow below to find out whether it could help you.
As you said, you got the target file path by this code:
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages/") + filename);
Before uploading files, please make sure that the directory in your web server “~/Content/UploadImages/” is existed.

Here is my test code:

MVC controller method

```html
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFiles()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
            if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var stream = fileContent.InputStream;
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileContent.FileName);
                string baseDir = Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImages/");
                if (!Directory.Exists(baseDir))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDir);
                var path = Path.Combine(baseDir, fileName);
                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            Flag = false,
            Message = string.Format("File Uploaded failed with exception:{0}", e.Message)
        });
    }
    return Json(new
    {
        Flag = true,
        Message = "File uploaded successfully!"
    });
}
```

Additionally, for long-term consideration, you could store your files on Azure Blob Storage which could bring you some benefits, such as:

1.Serving images or documents directly to a browser
2.Storing files for distributed access
3.When you scale up your site, your site could run in multiple Web Server instances which could access the same files & docs simultaneously

For more details, please refer to this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/